# HttpPost no recoge el modelo

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5

Dispongo de un modelos de datos que he de recoger de una ventana modal, hace todo bien, pero falla la obtención de datos

Dejo a continuación el código:

**Función ventana**

```
function ventanaModal(titulo, controlador, comprobacion, datos, tabla) {
       $("#dialog-message").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,

            modal: true,
            position: ['top', 60],
            width: 1200,
            resizable: false,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $('#dialog-message').css('overflow', 'hidden'); //this line does the actual hiding
            },
            title: "<div class='widget-header'><h4><i class='icon-ok'></i>"+ titulo+"</h4></div>",
            buttons: [{
                html: "<i class='fa fa-check'></i>&nbsp; Aceptar",
                "class": "aceptar btn btn-success btn-lg",
                "type": "button",
                "form": "modal-form-el",
                "id": "aceptarPost",
                click: function () {
                    var res = comprobacion();
                    if (res) {


                        $(this).dialog("close");

                        Aceptar(tabla);
                        //$(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
                    } 

                }
            }, {
                html: "Cancelar",
                "class": "btn btn-danger btn-lg",
                "type": "button",
                "data-dismiss": "modal",
                click: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");

                    //$(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
                }
                }]

        });

        if (datos === "") {
            res = $('#dialog-message').load(controlador);
            res.dialog('open');
        } else {
            ventanas.CargarDatosEnVentanas(controlador, datos);
        }

        function Aceptar(tabla) {
            var formContainer = $('form');
            console.log(formContainer.serialize());
            $.ajax({
                url: controlador,
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                data: formContainer.serialize(),
                success: function(result) {
                    avisos.manejarRespuestaAjax(result); 
                    if (tabla !== undefined) {
                        tabla.ajax.reload();
                    }
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
                    avisos.manejarErrorAjax(error); 
                }
            });
        }
    }
    ventanas.ventanaModal = ventanaModal;
```

**Modelo**

```
public class MuestrasVm
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Codigo { get; set; }
        public string CodRecepcion { get; set; }
        public decimal Acidez { get; set; }
        public decimal Grasa { get; set; }
        public decimal Humedad { get; set; }
        public decimal Rendimiento { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controlador**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Modificar(MuestrasVm vm)
        {
            try
            {                           
                _svcConfiguracion.UpdateMuestra(vm);//función interna para sql

                return AjaxResp.Ok("Modificar", "Modificar funciona");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _log.Error(e);
                return AjaxResp.Error("Modificar","Ha ocurrido un error al modificar");
            }
        }
```

**Vista**

```
//Boton modificar que abre la ventana
$('#modificar').click(function () {
            //fila seleccionada para modificar
            var selData = table.rows(".selected").data().toArray();

            if (selData.length > 0) {
                var codigo = String(selData[0].CodMuestra);
                var id = String(selData[0].Id);
                var codRecep = String(selData[0].CodRecepcion);
                var acidez = String(selData[0].Acidez);
                var grasa = String(selData[0].Grasa);
                var humedad = String(selData[0].Humedad);
                var rendimiento = String(selData[0].Rendimiento);

                //Generacion de datos para la ventan
                datos = { Id: id, Codigo: codigo, CodRecep: codRecep, Acidez: acidez, Grasa: grasa, Humedad: humedad, Rendimiento: rendimiento }
                try {
                    //llamada a función ventana
                    ventanas.ventanaModal("Modificar", "Modificar", comprobaciones, datos, table);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log("Error: " + e);
                }
            }           
        });
```

Genera la ventana correctamente, después, la función rellena los datos correctamente, pero al cambiarlos y pulsar aceptar, va sin problema al controlador, pero el modelo lo recibe vacío. He tratado de obtener los datos desde `Aceptar(tabla)` para ver si lo recibo pero no consigo acceder al elemento con los campos cambiados.
En el controlador cambie el modelo a `FormCollection` y recibia dos datos:

- "IdTabla"
- "tablaDatos_length"

Eso me hizo sospechar que otro modelo que se encuentra en la vista principal está afectando.

```
public class TablasVm
    {
        public int IdTabla { get; set; }
        public string Titulo { get; set; }
        public List<string> Cabecera { get; set; }
        public List<MuestrasVm> Muestras { get; set; }
    }
```

Si en caso de estar en lo cierto, ¿cómo puedo obtener sólo el segundo elemento? en caso de estar errado, ¿En qué?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con la ayuda de [farsSharp](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/28567/farssharp) logré comprender mi problema:

No estaba recogiendo el formulario por ningún lado, lo que hice para obtenerlo fue buscar los elementos del formulario y generar un json:

```
//Obtengo el contenedor del formulario
var items = $(this).context.children.item(0).children;
//Creo un array
item = {}
//Recorro el formulario
$.each(items, function (index, value) {
    //obtengo los divs
    let elements = value.children;
    //Al tener el formulario con mas de un input por fila, lo recorro
    $.each(elements, function (index, value) {
        //Obtengo los valores 
        let id = $('#' + value.id).children('input').attr('id');
        let valor = $('#' + value.id).children('input').val();
        //Genero el elemento y lo meto en mi json
        item[id] = valor;                               
        jsonObj.push(item);
    });
});
```

Después lo envío por parámetro a la función aceptar.

```
function Aceptar(json) {

    $.ajax({
        //le digo al ajax que le voy a pasar un json
        dataType: 'json',
        url: controlador,
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: json,//<-- envio el json
        success: function(result) {
            avisos.manejarRespuestaAjax(result); 
            if (tabla !== undefined) {
                 tabla.ajax.reload();
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
            avisos.manejarErrorAjax(error); 
        }
    });
}
```

Con todo esto ya recibo los datos en el controlador. Puede que no sea lo mas óptimo pero funciona.